# SASS Number variable calculation

Tags: sass

I have some CSS classes with increasing numbers. I'm using SCSS to apply different styles based on the number amount. Here is an example of the current SCSS I'm using

```
.content-wrap {    
    &.news-posts-1,
    &.news-posts-5,
    &.news-posts-9,
    &.news-posts-13,
    &.news-posts-17,
    &.news-posts-21,
    &.news-posts-25,
    &.news-posts-29,
    &.news-posts-33,
    &.news-posts-37,
    &.career-posts-41,
    &.career-posts-45,
    &.career-posts-49,
    &.career-posts-53,
    &.career-posts-57,
    &.career-posts-61,
    &.career-posts-65,
    &.career-posts-69 {
        .row {
            &::after {
                left: 25.7853403141%;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Surely there is a more elegant way of writing this, given that the numbers always increase by the same amount.